# How to resolve external host names in a centraliced place

Tags: domain-name-system, hosts-file

Our LAN is connected to another company's LAN and we have access to some of their servers, but not to their DNS server. When the users need access to some host by name, the solution I have is to go to their machine and add an entry to /etc/hosts

This is a bother so i was wondering if there is a way to add this info to our DNS server, or to any other place so I can avoid this duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always create a new zone in your DNS and enter the DNS entries there but, honestly, it makes a lot more sense to simply connect the DNS servers.

Ask them to allow you DNS to forward the request for their domain to their DNS servers: that way, they don't even have to open traffic to your whole network, they only need to allow DNS from your own servers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Stephane!

In fact, I have forwarded the requests for their domain to a DNS server they have provided, but it seems that it doesn't solve some names. I don't know if they have different DNS servers or something but I'd like a way to workaround this.

Comment: make sure you are using FQDN and not just host names. The later will usually be resolved using the "default" local domain and that will not match.

Comment: Well this worked fine enough.